# access 2013 increasing quantity in a table field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Good day.  I'm a little stumped about what is happening in my code.  I have a userform which collects `txtQntyRecd` and `cboSupplySource`. I calculate the `lookupValue`. And it works just fine. It successfully places the `txtQntyRecd` in the correct `tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity` location.   The code is:

```
    updateQnty = "UPDATE tblSupplySources INNER JOIN ((tblWarehouseLocations " & _
            "INNER JOIN tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation ON tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID = tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.SWLocation_ID)) " & _
            "ON tblSupplySources.SupplySourceID = tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID " & _
            "SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = '" & Me.txtQntyRecd & "'" & _
              "WHERE (((tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID)= " & Me.cboSupplySource & ") " & _
             " AND ((tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID)=" & lookupValue & "))" 
     CurrentDb.Execute updateQnty, dbFailOnError
```

What I want to do is add the next quantity to the same location.  I get weird results if I change the `SET` statement to the following:

```
    SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity + '" & Me.txtQntyRecd & "'"
```

If I put 200 in the first statement, I get 200 in my `WQuantity` field.  When I change to the second statement and I try to add 1 to the 200 I get a result of 211.  If I add 1 again, the result is 223. Add 1 again, the result is 236.

Could someone explain what is happening and why the results aren't 201, 202 and 203?  In the future I will need to subtract quantities from `WQuantity` as well.

Thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer as the answer if it's answered your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, just inserting your set statement into my update query is not working, probably because I do not know the exact syntax to use.  Putting your set statement into my UPDATE query causes the following error: "Run-time error '3061' : Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Comment: ok, updated answer for you

Comment: I'm sorry but, although the code works, the results are still a mess.  I started tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity with a quantity of 200.  I put a quantity of 1 in Me!txtQntyRecd.  After running the code 4 times (adding 1 each time) WQuantity had the following values: 209, 219, 230, 242. The numbers are increasing incrementally. So, you did answer my question as to how to write the code. Can you tell me what to look for to solve the next problem?

Comment: check that your sql statement doesn't return multiple rows. if it does, it'd add multiple times causing the error you see.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with me.  I'm obviously a newbie with Access, and I appreciate your help. I'm not sure exactly how to check for multiple rows - the sql statement seems pretty straight forward (to me).  And if it was doing that wouldn't my quantity increase a fixed amount vs. incrementing each time?

Comment: No idea, I thought you may be inserting other data elsewhere. That's where I suggest you start looking though!

Comment: yeah, don't know either.  I'll try an update in one stand-alone table and then move to the more complicated scenario with junction tables. If it happens in a single table (no relationships to other tables) the solution may be a 16 oz hammer to the CPU. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem.  I created a SELECT statement to get the present amount in WQuantity.    Now quantityReceived  =  Me!txtQntyRecd  + the present amount.  With SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = " & quantityReceived it works fine.   However, if just seems so cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding quotes around an integer and appending it as a string. Change it to:

```
".....
SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity + " & val(Me!txtQntyRecd) & "....
...."
```

I've changed the `.` to a `!` as I think it's still a nice distinction between objects properties and controls, and used the `val` function as it converts the string number value to the integer value.

This is your query in full:

```
' When I use values from controls, I like to store them in vars
Dim quantityReceived As integer
quantityReceived = val(Me!txtQntyRecd)

updateQnty = "UPDATE tblSupplySources INNER JOIN ((tblWarehouseLocations " & _
        "INNER JOIN tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation ON tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID = tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.SWLocation_ID)) " & _
        "ON tblSupplySources.SupplySourceID = tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID " & _
        "SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity + " & quantityReceived & _
          " WHERE (((tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID)= " & Me.cboSupplySource & ") " & _
         " AND ((tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID)=" & lookupValue & "))"
```

Comment: I figured it was a string issue.  What is the correct syntax for the statement ?  I have tried:    "SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity =  tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity + Val(Me!txtQntyRecd) "  and I get 'too few parameters'.

Comment: What do you mean? Correct syntax for what statement?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I created a SELECT query to get the present amount in WQuantity. Now quantityReceived = Me!txtQntyRecd + the present amount. With SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = " & quantityReceived it works fine. However, if just seems so cumbersome.

```
    ' lookupValue gives the index into the tblWarehouseLocations where WQuantity resides
    Dim lookupValue As Integer
lookupValue = DLookup("[WLocation_ID]", "[tblWarehouseLocations]", "[Location_Name] = '" & Me.cboWLocation & "'")

'Define SQL Query
strSQL = "select tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity FROM tblWarehouseLocations WHERE (((tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID)= " & lookupValue & "))"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If IsNull(rs!WQuantity) Then
    dbvalue = 0
Else
    dbvalue = rs!WQuantity
End If

Dim quantityReceived As Integer
quantityReceived = Val(Me!txtQntyRecd) + dbvalue


updateQnty = "UPDATE tblSupplySources INNER JOIN ((tblWarehouseLocations " & _
    "INNER JOIN tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation ON tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID = tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.SWLocation_ID)) " & _
    "ON tblSupplySources.SupplySourceID = tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID " & _
    "SET tblWarehouseLocations.WQuantity = " & quantityReceived & _
    " WHERE (((tblSupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID)= " & Me.cboSupplySource & ") " & _
    " AND ((tblWarehouseLocations.WLocation_ID)=" & lookupValue & "))"

    CurrentDb.Execute updateQnty, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Dude!... So you took my answer, rewrote it, and posted it and accepted it as an aswer? your comment below mine was specific to your problem, not a whole answer! You write "Thanks for taking the time with me" then kick me in the teeth by stealing my answer!

Comment: Wait a minute.  I did nothing to dishonor your time and help.  I was looking for a whole answer and you put me on the correct path.  I couldn't have done it without your help.  If you think I was taking credit for the whole thing you have misinterpreted my intentions.  I did not intend to take credit for the answer, because I only did the last part.  This is probably because I may not have asked the original question properly or thoroughly.  If I've done something wrong I apologize but I never thought I did nor had I intended to steal your answer.  I had  even check marked your answer.

Comment: To further clarify - I should have simply said 'Here is the final coding' as opposed to saying 'I have solved the problem.'  Again, I apologize if I have offended or misrepresented.  My intent was only to post the final coding and not to take credit for anyone else's work.

Comment: I lose the credit for helping you as you unmarked it as the answer. You already stated what you did in a comment above, so there was no need for this "answer".